# Operate Genius ColorPage-Vivied 1200xe on Ubuntu14.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, software-installation, scanner, input-devices, scanning

I can not install the scanner Genius ColorPage-Vivied 1200XE on Ubuntu 14.04LTS, the scanner utilities can not recognize the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing a Genius ColorPage-Vivid 1200XE scanner in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

**Step 1:**
Locate a small firmware file named 'CCD569.fw' with size 8KB in any location on the PC. This binary file is required by the XSane scanning package to correctly communicate with the scanner. The firmware file can be [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?q1u87k4jhwuh465):

**Step 2:**
Open the terminal and type the command ''sudo nautilus'' command. This will open a file browser with root permissions.

Go to this path:''/usr/share/sane/'' and create a folder with name: ''gt68xx''

Copy the file ''CCD569.fw'' from where you have located it, into the folder ''/usr/share/sane/gt68xx''

**Step 3:**
Close the file browser (with elevated permissions) and the terminal.
Delete any 'temp' folder that you may have created.

You are now ready to start scanning with 'Xsane' and with 'Simple Scan' applications.

Note:
Xsane is much better scanning package than Simple Scan becouse it give us a complete control of all possible parameters, which are automatically saved on exit.